# Toggle button to switch between desktop site and mobile-first responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

When I make mobile first responsive site. I put all the css in 1 file, it looks like:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-hs-min) {
   /* rules for mobile horizontal (480 > 768)  */
}
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
   /* rules for tablet (768 > 992) */
}
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
   /* rules for desktop (992 > 1200) */
}
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
   /* rules for large (> 1200) */
}
```

And I want to create a toggle button to switch between non responsive and responsive. If the css are in seperate files, I could use js to unload the responsive css. But since they are all in 1 file, how could I do the toggle?

Many thanks.

Comment: What if I create 3 css files. and embed them in <head> in order like this: 
`
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> //Universe styles goes here 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css"> //All styles for media query from 0px - 1199px
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css"> //All styles for 1200px +
`

when click on toggle button, responsive.css style sheet will be removed from the <head>

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have 2 separate HTML pages, and give one of their body tags a custom class, then have the button link to the other page. Then style the page based on that class.

You could also use JS to add a style tag to the header that overrides the original stylesheet. If you do that, make sure it gets put in after the original link.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I see what you mean. I will give it a try.